# Callback for android app chooser bottom sheet

Tags: android, android-intent

I hit a web search query intent from an activity of my app and want to finish this activity once the user has selected an option from the app chooser bottom sheet.

Is there a way to wait for the app chooser bottomSheet to be resolved and send a callback to my app for the same ?